# "Bitwise and" in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am representing a list of values in Django using one bit each of an arbitrarily long `BinaryField`. In the template, I would like to enable checkboxes corresponding to the matching bits.

```
  {% for element in elements %}
  <li class="list-group-item 
      {% if selected_elements & element.value %} 
          list-group-item-primary active 
      {% endif %}" id="{{ element.value }}">
   {{ element.description }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

`selected_elements` is the unsigned integer representation of the values that the user selected (assume `9` which is `1001`). `element.value` is a geometric progression `1 2 4 8 ...`

So, consider the `{% if selected_elements & element.value %}` within loop:

```
1001 & 0001 = True
1001 & 0010 = False
1001 & 0100 = False
1001 & 1000 = True
... all remaining elements => False
```

However, the `&` seems to cause trouble when the page is accessed.

> Could not parse the remainder: '&' from '&' (<class django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError'>)

Is there any way to use bitwise operators in Django (1.10) templates?

Comment: Note that `1001 & 0011` is `0001`, not `False`

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complicated way of doing things. Since you are already having to do some work in the view in order to get your geometric progression, you should take that opportunity instead to parse your bitfield into something more usable, ie a list of selected values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion @DanielRoseman. I'll measure the runtime and utilization of doing this in the view (your comment) v/s the custom filter (your answer) and choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Django template language does not support bitwise operations, but you could [write a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def bitwise_and(value, arg):
    return bool(value & arg)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load bitwise_tags %}
{% if selected_elements|bitwise_and:element.value %}
```